# Changing from localhost:8888 to localhost

Tags: multisite, wp-config

I have just changed ports on MAMP from :8888 to :80 for localhost in order to setup a WordPress multisite for local development. However I have several sites with separate installations that are in my htdocs folder and previously used localhost:8888 as a root.

I did the following things in order :

1. Opened wp-config and changed the Mysql hostname to `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`
2. Went to the options table of the database and changed the siteurl and home.
3. I cleared my .htaccess file
4. Cleared my browser cache.

Still, when I am at the index for localhost I am still being redirected to localhost:8888. I'm sure other people have had this problem and yet I can't seem to find the same question.

Interestingly enough I have access to admin just not to the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat this just like you would when [changing domains](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change).

The short version is:

1. You need to change the WordPress Address and Site Address in
   Settings->General. You have to change both
2. Or [edit `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) to alter the same values as in step #1. This one is easiest if you've already lost part of the site functionality.
3. And alter the hard-coded addresses in the DB. I have always used [Velvet
   Blues Update Urls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) for that.

The Codex has a link to a helper script and a longer 15 step process. Read through that carefully before beginning.

Comment: Ah, I see. Missed the WordPress address but I would have thought I could find it in the options table. Just out of curiosity where is it kept in the DB? I'll have to try that Velvet Blues update urls. Thank you once again :)

Comment: It is in the options table. Look for `siteurl` and `home`